# How to achieve privilege separation between multiple services (e.g. uwsgi) proxied by nginx?

Tags: nginx, file-permissions, groups, uwsgi

One website I maintain is composed of multiple local applications, all proxied by the same *nginx* instance. Each application is running under its own user and exposing a *unix socket* writable by the web server group `www-data`.

All application users are part of the `www-data` group, so they can *chown* their sockets. **How can i improve my setup, so that a vulnerability in one application can no longer be used to attempt further privilege escalation through direct connections to the other sockets?**

*My previous solution:* Create a new group for every user and add the web server to all those. This solution is less preferable, as it complicates adding/removing applications & requires a hard restart of the web server to update groups.

Comment: If it is writable by the user, and `www-data`, and nobody else, what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to how services [can inherit privileged ports from *systemd*](https://serverfault.com/questions/848306/does-systemd-allow-for-functionality-like-authbind-where-you-can-allow-a-non-ro/848916#848916), they can receive access to local sockets they would otherwise have no permission to open.
*Systemd* creates the unix socket and passes only the file description to the service - this way, the service does not need access permissions on the socket file.

Setup the socket using `/etc/systemd/system/example.socket` like this: (read `man systemd.socket`)

```
[Unit]
PartOf=example.service
[Socket]
SocketUser=www-data
SocketMode=0600
ListenStream=%t/example.sock
```

And use that socket in `/etc/systemd/system/example.service` like this: (read `man systemd.unit`)

```
[Unit]
Requires=example.socket
After=example.socket
[Service]
User=example
WorkingDirectory=~
ExecStart=/usr/bin/uwsgi --uwsgi-socket=fd://3 --opt2 --opt3 ..
```

*Note that many programs, including uwsgi, do understand `LISTEN_FDS` in their environment, so hard-coding file descriptor 3 is often unnecessary.*

Apply and start the unit using:

```
systemctl dameon-reload
systemctl start example.service
```

If a service account then attempts to open the socket of another service, he will not succeed - the sockets are owned and exclusively readable by `www-data` (i.e. only the web server running under that user can access them).